# Ignore missing values while finding min in Rcpp

Tags: rcpp

I am trying to find the minimum of 2 values from 2 vectors in Rcpp. But the following does not compile:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;



// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector timesTwo(int time_length, double BXadd, 
                       NumericVector vn_complete, NumericVector vn1_complete) {
  
  // Empty vectors
  NumericVector BX (time_length);
  
  for(int t = 0; t < time_length; t++) {

    BX[t] = BXadd * sqrt(std::min(na_omit(vn_complete[t], vn1_complete[t])));
    
  }

  return BX;
  
  // return vn_complete[0];
}

  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

It works if I don't use `na_omit`.

#### R code for running the function:

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp("test.cpp")

timesTwo(5, 2, 5:9, 1:5)
```

Comment: I fear your parens are wrong. You only supply one argument to `std::min()`. Is that you intent?  Moreover, what is `na.omit(scalar1, scalar2)`  supposed to do?

Comment: I have 2 numeric vectors `vn_complete` and `vn1_complete`. In a given iteration of `for-loop`, I want to extract one value each from these vectors and find the minimum. One of the two values could be `NA`, so I want to remove it. In `R` I can do `min(vn_complete[t], vn1_complete[t], na.rm=TRUE)`. What is the alternative in `Rcpp`? Also, I have re-checked the parentheses, I am supplying 2 arguments, not 1 to `std::min()`

Comment: I fear you are "trying to write R code in C++".  The `na_omit()` is your issue here, and I think it just does not work the way you think it works.

Comment: I found the usage of `na_omit()` [here](https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/210_rcpp_functions.html#functions-related-to-na-inf-nan). Could you please guide me how I can do `min(vn_complete[t], vn1_complete[t], na.rm=TRUE)`? I have searched a lot but could not find any examples so far.

Comment: .... which clearly show `na_omit()` to have *single* argument yet your code has two in `na_omit(vn_complete[t], vn1_complete[t])` and that simply cannot work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What follows below is a slightly non-sensical answer (as it only works with vectors not containing NA) but it has all the component your code has, and it compiles.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector foo(int time_length, double BXadd,
                  NumericVector vn_complete, NumericVector vn1_complete) {

    // Empty vectors
    NumericVector BX (time_length);
    vn_complete = na_omit(vn_complete);
    vn1_complete = na_omit(vn1_complete);
    for(int t = 0; t < time_length; t++) {
        double a = vn_complete[t];
        double b = vn1_complete[t];
        BX[t] = BXadd * std::sqrt(std::min(a,b));
    }
    return BX;
}

// Edited version with new function added 
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector foo2(double BXadd, NumericVector vn_complete, 
                   NumericVector vn1_complete) {
    return BXadd * sqrt(pmin(vn_complete, vn1_complete));
}

/*** R
foo(5, 2, 5:9, 1:5)
foo2(5, 2, 5:9, 1:5)
*/
```

For a real solution you will have to think harder about what the removal of NA is supposed to do *as it will alter the lenth of your vectors too*.  So this still needs work.

Lastly, your whole function can be written in R as

```
2 * sqrt(pmin(5:9, 1:5))
```

and I think you could write *that same expression* using Rcpp sugar too as we have `pmin()` and `sqrt()`:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector foo2(double BXadd, NumericVector vn_complete, 
                   NumericVector vn1_complete) {
    return BXadd * sqrt(pmin(vn_complete, vn1_complete));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here, removing `NA` before the `for-loop` would result in improper comparison of the two values for estimating the `min()` as you pointed out. So, upon reflection I think doing `if(vn_complete[t] < vn1_complete[t]) {
      
      BX[t] = BXadd * sqrt(vn_complete[t]);
      
    } else if (vn_complete[t] > vn1_complete[t]) {
      
      BX[t] = BXadd * sqrt(vn1_complete[t]);
      
    } ` makes more sense. This will result in `NA` if either of the `vn_` vectors are `NA`. But I can break the loop when that happens. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: As I said, I only added it to show you that it works fine "as intended" with a single argument.